# How to read json file and serialize it in custom class?

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, file-handling

I have following JSON saved in menu.json file:

```
       {
          "menu": {
                    "menuitems": [
                     {
                          "label": "Account",
                          "listview": "Account List"
                      },
                      {
                          "label": "Documents",
                          "listview": "Document List"
                      }
                                ]
                  }
       }
```

I have written this data to the file manually.I retrieve this data using following function:

```
        public ActionResult GetFromFile(string path)// path points to the menu.json file
       {
          StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
          string filedata = sr.ReadToEnd();
          Menu menu = JsonSerializer.DeserializeToString<Menu>(filedata);
          return Json(menu, JsonRequestBehavior.Allowget);

       }
```

When I get the response as menu , I am not able to get it separated in the class fields. moreover, I have a single class and so how do I store my json file data to this class?? Will there be any modifications in the class structure? My Menu Class is as follows:

```
    public class Menu

    {
       public string Label {get;set;}
       public string Listview {get;set;}
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serialization has an extra, unnamed container above menu. Your class structure needs to look like:

```
public class container
{
    public menu menu { get; set; }
}

public class menu
{
    public menuitem[] menuitems { get; set; }
}

public class menuitem
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Listview { get; set; }
}
```

And to deserialize, you can use:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("menu.json");
string filedata = sr.ReadToEnd();
var menus = js.Deserialize<container>(filedata);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rename your Menu class to MenuItem:

```
public class MenuItem
{
   public string Label { get; set; }
   public string Listview { get; set; }
}
```

And create a new Menu class that has a list of MenuItems:

```
public class Menu
{
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples of serialization here http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx using JSON.Net

Answer (score 0):

Your class structure should be something similar to the following

```
public class Menu
    {
       public List<MenuItem> menuItems {get;set;}
   }

public class MenuItem
{
       public string Label {get;set;}
       public string Listview {get;set;}
}
```